# What role does FederationMetadata.xml play in WIF?

Tags: wif

I'm trying to develop an authentication plugin for an ASP.NET MVC3 application that would use WIF for authentication. Since it's a plugin with an in-system configuration, I avoid touching the web.config file of the app or anything else. I've got it working, but now I'm trying to specify what claims the STS should send my app, and it seems that `FederationMetadata.xml` is involved, but I cannot find confirmation of that. In fact, I cannot find any information on this enigmatic file at all. What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FederationMetadata tells potential relying parties what information the STS provides.

Your claims should be detailed in the `EntityDescriptor/RoleDescriptor/fed:ClaimTypesOffered` section

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/card/archive/2010/06/25/using-federation-metadata-to-establish-a-relying-party-trust-in-ad-fs-2-0.aspx

Answer (score 1):

FederationMetadata is a 2 way exchange.  It is used to tell the Identity Provider *WHAT* claims you require and the Identity Provider can use the metadata to tell your application *WHAT* claims it offers by default.

This way you can ensure your application has all the claims support it requires when integrating with differing identity providers.